How to monitor system usage when running a script over multiple cors/threads?
I have written a specific script in Ubuntu 22.04 (After testing, I can say,it also run on 24.04) to monitor some system parameters while a specific command is running. The command in question is running another tool, which is spread over several cores/threads.
I would like to monitor the usage of memory, a specific file size, which cores and threads are used. The script is attached below.
I'm sort of happy with the results so far, but I was wondering if it can be done better.
One thing I can't manage to monitor is the %CPU I can see when executing the top command and then press 1. I can see there the %CPU usage of the command for each core. I don't seems to find the way to do it programmatically.
I'm not sure if it is even possible, but I would like to know which of my processes is running on which thread(s) and if possible to quantify it.
I would appreciate any suggestions or advices to make it more elegant.
thanks
Assa
#!/bin/bash

process_name="dotnet"
folder_path="Output/combined"
log_file="usage_log.csv"

#Rename log file if exists
if [ -e "$log_file" ]; then
    # Get the current timestamp
    timestamp=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
# Construct the new file name with the timestamp
    new_log_file="${log_file%.*}_$timestamp.${log_file##*.}"
    
    # Rename the log file
    mv "$log_file" "$new_log_file"
    echo "Log file renamed to $new_log_file"
else
    echo "Log file does not exist."
fi

echo "Timestamp,PID,%MEM %CPU RSS_GB VSZ_GB,Threads,Folder_Size" > $log_file

while true; do
    timestamp=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    
    # Get all PIDs for the process name
    pids=$(pgrep -f $process_name)
    
    if [ -z "$pids" ]; then
        echo "Process not found"
        break
    fi
    
    folder_size=$(du -sh $folder_path | cut -f1)
    
    for pid in $pids; do
    # Extract memory info and convert to GB
    mem_info=$(ps -o %mem,%cpu,rss,vsz -p $pid --no-headers | \
               awk '{printf "%s %s %.2f %.2f", $1, $2, $3/1048576, $4/1048576}')
    # Extract number of threads
    threads=$(ps -o nlwp -p $pid --no-headers)
    # Extract CPU cores
    cores=$(taskset -pc $pid | awk -F: '{print $2}' | tr -d ' ')

    # Extract CPU cores allowed
    allowed_cores=$(taskset -pc $pid | awk -F: '{print $2}' | tr -d ' ')
     
    #interval after $pid removed
    cores_used=$(pidstat -p $pid | awk -v pid="$pid" ' 
    BEGIN { cores = 0; }
    $4 == pid && $10 > 0 { cores++; }
    END { print cores; }
    ')
   
    echo "$timestamp, $pid ,$mem_info,$threads,$cores,$cores_used, $folder_size" >> $log_file
    done
    
    sleep 30
done

The output looks like that:
Timestamp,PID,%MEM %CPU RSS_GB VSZ_GB,Threads,Folder_Size
...
2024-07-23 13:42:40, 2798428 ,0.0 29.2 0.35 1018.40,   7,0-63,1, 2.7G
2024-07-23 13:42:40, 2798434 ,0.0 30.5 0.37 1018.40,   7,0-63,1, 2.7G
2024-07-23 13:42:40, 2798436 ,0.0 31.5 0.36 1018.40,   7,0-63,1, 2.7G
2024-07-23 13:42:40, 2798438 ,0.0 32.2 0.34 1018.40,   7,0-63,1, 2.7G
2024-07-23 13:42:40, 2798441 ,0.0 33.8 0.39 1018.40,   7,0-63,1, 2.7G
2024-07-23 13:42:40, 2798447 ,0.0 33.0 0.40 1018.40,   7,0-63,1, 2.7G
2024-07-23 13:42:40, 2798452 ,0.0 26.9 0.38 1018.40,   7,0-63,1, 2.7G
...


What is the version of Ubuntu being used?

I'm using the LTS 22.04

Please edit the question and add this info.

Since me posting the question, I have modified my script to give me some more necessary information, such as the active and idle cores as well as the size of intermediate folders I'm interested in keeping as small as possible (as long as I have the storage space on my machine.
The script is below. All comments and improvement (also some critics of course) are welcome.
#!/bin/bash

process_name="dotnet"
folder_path="/home/ubuntu/raw_data/" # this is the path in the ubuntu AWS machine
#folder_path="/fs/pool/pool-cox-projects-bioinformatics/AG_Cox/AWS/big_runs/PXD041421_timstof/DIA/combined"
log_file="TT_DIA_usage_m7i.48xlarge_log.csv"
#log_file="TT_DIA_usage_log.csv"
mqpar_file="mqpar_timstof_DIA_m7i.48xlarge.xml"
batch_size=100
# interval=1  # Interval in seconds for sampling CPU usage

#Rename log file if exists
if [ -e "$log_file" ]; then
    # Get the current timestamp
    timestamp=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
# Construct the new file name with the timestamp
    new_log_file="${log_file%.*}_$timestamp.${log_file##*.}"
    
    # Rename the log file
    mv "$log_file" "$new_log_file"
    echo "Log file renamed to $new_log_file"
    touch $log_file
else
    echo "Log file does not exist."
    touch $log_file
fi

# First step is to calculate the batch size of the rwo files. The data is taken from the mqpar file
## extract the names to a tmp file
sed -n '/filePaths/,/filePaths/{ /filePaths/b; /filePaths/b; p }' ${mqpar_file} > filesNames
## remove the prefix and suffix patterns
sed -i -e 's/<string>//g' -e 's/<\/string>//g' filesNames
# split the file into the separated batches based on the batch number used for the run
split -l ${batch_size} --numeric-suffixes=1 filesNames batch_
# Go through the created files in each of the lists and calculate the total size for each of them. The information is added to the head of the log file.
for list in batch_*; 
do
 echo -n $list": " >> $log_file
 find $(cat "$list") -type f -exec du -b {} + | awk '{sum += $1} END {printf "Total: %.2f GB\n", sum / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)}' >> $log_file
done
# Clean tmp files
rm batch_0* filesNames.txt

#echo "Timestamp,PID,%MEM,%CPU,RSS_GB,VSZ_GB,Threads,Cores_Used,Allowed_Cores,Folder_Size" > $log_file
echo "Timestamp,PID,%MEM %CPU RSS_GB VSZ_GB,Threads,Folder_Size,Core_Usage">> $log_file

while true; do
    timestamp=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    
    # Get all PIDs for the process name
    pids=$(pgrep -f $process_name)
    
    if [ -z "$pids" ]; then
        echo "Process not found"
        break
    fi
 # This was modified to include also the temporary folders, which are not in the 'combined' folder.
 # This must be adjusted each time a different machine is used. For tims-tof data the folders ends with .d, the intermediate ones don't have this .d
    folder_size=$(find $folder_path  -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name '*.d' ! -name '.' ! -name 'raw_data' -exec du -sb {} + | awk '{total += $1} END {print total}' | numfmt --to=iec)
#    folder_size=$(du -sh $folder_path | cut -f1)

# -maxdepth 1 ensures it looks only at the top-level subdirectories.
# ! -name '*.d' excludes directories ending with .d. the '.' and 'raw_data' exclude the complete folder claculation. This leaves only those directories without a '.d'. 
# du -sb computes the sizes.
# awk sums up the sizes, 
# numfmt --to=iec converts the result to human-readable format.

    for pid in $pids; do
    # Extract memory info and convert to GB
    mem_info=$(ps -o %mem,%cpu,rss,vsz -p $pid --no-headers | \
               awk '{printf "%s %s %.2f %.2f", $1, $2, $3/1048576, $4/1048576}')
    # Extract number of threads
    threads=$(ps -o nlwp -p $pid --no-headers)
    # Extract CPU cores
    cores=$(taskset -pc $pid | awk -F: '{print $2}' | tr -d ' ')

    # Extract CPU cores allowed
    allowed_cores=$(taskset -pc $pid | awk -F: '{print $2}' | tr -d ' ')
     
    #interval after $pid removed
    cores_used=$(pidstat -p $pid | awk -v pid="$pid" ' 
    BEGIN { cores = 0; }
    $4 == pid && $10 > 0 { cores++; }
    END { print cores; }
    ')

    # Check if cores_used is empty and print debug info
    if [ -z "$cores_used" ]; then
        echo "Debug: cores_used is empty for PID $pid"
        # Optionally print raw pidstat output for debugging
        pidstat -p $pid -t $interval 2>/dev/null
    fi
    
    #cores_high_activity=$(mpstat -P ALL 1 1 | awk '/^[0-9]/ { if ($(NF) < 90) printf "CPU" $2 "," }')
    total_active_cores=$(mpstat -P ALL 1 1 | awk '/^[0-9]/ { if ($(NF) < 30) count++ } END { print count }')
    #cores_zero_activity=$(mpstat -P ALL 1 1 | awk '/^[0-9]/ { if ($(NF) == 100) printf "CPU" $2 "," }')
    total_idle_cores=$(mpstat -P ALL 1 1 | awk '/^[0-9]/ { if ($(NF) == 100) count++ } END { print count }')

    # Remove trailing commas from the lists
    cores_high_activity=${cores_high_activity%,}
    cores_zero_activity=${cores_zero_activity%,}

    # Count the number of cores in each category
    count_high=$(echo "$cores_high_activity" | grep -o "," | wc -l)
    count_zero=$(echo "$cores_zero_activity" | grep -o "," | wc -l)

    # Adjust counts for cases where no cores are found
    count_high=$((count_high + 1)) # Adds 1 to account for the first core in the list
    count_zero=$((count_zero + 1))

    # Handle empty lists (if no cores meet the conditions)
    [ -z "$cores_high_activity" ] && count_high=0
    #[ -z "$cores_zero_activity" ] && count_zero=0

#    core_stats=$(echo "Cores with >70% activity: $cores_high_activity ($count_high cores), Total idle cores: $total_idle_cores")
    core_stats=$(echo "#Cores with >70% activity: $total_active_cores, Total idle cores: $total_idle_cores")
    
#    echo "$timestamp,$pid,$mem_info,$threads,$cores_used,$allowed_cores,$folder_size" >> $log_file
    echo "$timestamp, $pid ,$mem_info,$threads,$cores,$cores_used, $folder_size, $core_stats" >> $log_file
    done
    
    sleep 30
done

Output looks like that:
$ tail -f TT_DIA_usage_m7i.48xlarge_log.csv
Timestamp,PID,%MEM %CPU RSS_GB VSZ_GB,Threads,Folder_Size
2024-08-21 08:32:05, 2529250 ,0.0 0.0 0.05 1516.96, 193,0-191,0, 1.5G, #Cores with >70% activity: 182, Total idle cores: 9
2024-08-21 08:32:05, 2539965 ,0.0 102 0.11 1511.50, 197,0-191,0, 1.5G, #Cores with >70% activity: 183, Total idle cores: 7
2024-08-21 08:32:05, 2539968 ,0.0 102 0.11 1511.50, 197,0-191,0, 1.5G, #Cores with >70% activity: 182, Total idle cores: 11
2024-08-21 08:32:05, 2539971 ,0.0 101 0.11 1511.50, 197,0-191,0, 1.5G, #Cores with >70% activity: 183, Total idle cores: 10
2024-08-21 08:32:05, 2539982 ,0.0 99.6 0.12 1511.50, 197,0-191,0, 1.5G, #Cores with >70% activity: 183, Total idle cores: 8
2024-08-21 08:32:05, 2539986 ,0.0 99.5 0.12 1511.50, 198,0-191,0, 1.5G, #Cores with >70% activity: 182, Total idle cores: 12
2024-08-21 08:32:05, 2539993 ,0.0 101 0.11 1511.50, 197,0-191,0, 1.5G, #Cores with >70% activity: 183, Total idle cores: 9
2024-08-21 08:32:05, 2540001 ,0.0 101 0.11 1511.50, 197,0-191,0, 1.5G, #Cores with >70% activity: 182, Total idle cores: 8
2024-08-21 08:32:05, 2540010 ,0.0 99.7 0.11 1511.50, 197,0-191,0, 1.5G, #Cores with >70% activity: 183, Total idle cores: 8
2024-08-21 08:32:05, 2540018 ,0.0 100 0.12 1511.50, 197,0-191,0, 1.5G, #Cores with >70% activity: 182, Total idle cores: 9
...

